# SSIS OData Detecting decimal precision wrong

Tags: ssis, odata

I am reading data.from OData Feed, but while reading the data read with wrong precision, it completely avoid any decimal part, ie, I am getting 125 instead of 125.25.

Please help us to resolve thi issue.

I tried to change the precision, scale to get the result, but got error, which says DT_Numeric value cannot be changed.